# C Programming: The output window in vs code is empty

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[the screenshot shows what the empty field and the code written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnAUb.png)I have just set up VS Code for programming with C, I installed all the necessary things (gcc, gdb..etc)
But when I started writing basic code, vs code shows an empty output after I run it

Comment: The file has undaved changes. Save it and re-compile.

Answer (score 0):

## Installation (Ignore if installed)

#### Windows

Install mingw/gcc/clang compiler and then add it to the path.

#### GNU/Linux

Install gcc/clang compiler using your package manager.

```
Arch Based Distros: `sudo pacman -S gcc`
Ubuntu/Other debian based distro: `sudo apt install gcc g++`
```

Now, install C/C++ extension for VSCODE here's the link [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)

#### Installing the C/C++ VSCODE extenion

Or you can directly install it through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and paste this snippet `ext install ms-vscode.cpptools`.

## Compiling

Now, open your terminal in VSCODE and run `gcc Test.c -o test` and then run `./test` to execute your program.

Or, if you have installed `clang` compiler then the terminal command goes here `clang Test.c -o test` and then run `./test` to execute your program.

Comment: Thank you. It worked but the result or the printed text, in this case, is shown in the Terminal and the output is still empty. This creates a problem when I write long code with a higher probability of making a mistake; I can't know the error and so many tabs are starting to open when I debug the code like launch.json. 
And this sign also appears: Unable to open 'mingw_pformat.c': Unable to read file 'c:\M\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\mingw-w64\mingw-w64-crt\stdio\mingw_pformat.c' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\M\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\mingw-w64\mingw-w64-crt\stdio\mingw_pformat.c').

Comment: @AzizElouaer If you have installed C/C++ extension in VSCODE, then press **`F5`** and then your result will be on `Output` tab. NOTE: Output tab is only for debugging in VSCODE. If this worked then, up-vote my answer and mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

Main method have return type int, try return 0; after printf. Or you need to add argument to main method, in java program i know we can not run program without argument.
Or
Try make void main method

Comment: For `main` function, the final `return` statement is not required. There is an implicit `return 0;` defined by the standard in case that is missing in the code. Also while parameter list should not be empty, it is still allowed. Making `main` a `void` function is completely wrong. Return type is defined to be `int` except for freestanding environments. Besides that, if any of these were the reason for a problem, there would be an compilation error presented.